# sending unicoded strings in ajax.post request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, livechat

I am using "livechatstarterkit" for chatting functionality in my mvc web app. But my web application is in a right to left language and users have names in Persian.

The problem here is that when a user with Persian name log-in as operator his name encoded cause of the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var intervalId;
        var chatId = '@(Model)';
        var lastMsgId = 0;
        var opname = '@ViewBag.opname';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            getMsgs();
            intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
                getMsgs();
            }, 3210);

            $('#chatText').keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $.post('/chat/addmsg', { id: chatId, from: opname, msg: $('#chatText').val() }, function (data) { getMsgs(); });
                    $('#chatText').val('');
                }
            });
.....
```

But as I debug my app, I see the messages from operator are not beign sent, in fact the `$.post('/chat/addmsg'....` code is not executed and request is not sent to proper action.

here is some exaple of opname in jscript : "`&#1662;&#1588;&#1578;&#1740;&#1576;&#1575;&#1606;&#1740;`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
var opname = '@ViewBag.opname';
```

with:

```
var opname = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.opname));
```

Also to test if <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed in a cross browser fashion, your code should look like this:

```
$('#chatText').keyup(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("addmsg", "chat")';
        var msg = $(this).val();
        $.post(url, { id: chatId, from: opname, msg: msg }, function (data) { 
            getMsgs(); 
        });
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url:"ax.php?action=post&save=1", 
  type: "POST", 
  data:
    { tabName: "basic", 
    rid: $("textarea#id").val(), 
    col:"id", 
    val:$(this).prev().val() },
  success:function (result){ setSpan(result);},
  dataType:"html", contentType: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" } )
```

What about using `$.ajax` function so that you can set `contentType` property.

> When sending data to the server, use this content-type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", which is fine for most cases. If
>   you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax() then it'll always be
>   sent to the server (even if no data is sent). Data will always be
>   transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this
>   appropriately on the server side.